# Lauch Acrobat Reader From Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Wanted to know if we can launch acobat reader from javascript.

The requirement is like, when user clicks a button a PDf should be downloaded and opened in adobe reader on the client machine.

Comment: So, you want a PDF download button. Something like `<a href="path/to/file.pdf">Download PDF!</a>` should do just fine.

Comment: You can't force a client to do what *you* want with a file once it's downloaded. You can just force the browser to download it instead of opening it with the internal PDF plugin (if present). But the user can always refuse to download the document.

Comment: Download is not the question. It is to launch the adobe reader with the downloaded file automatically.

Comment: You can't force the client to open the file. That's simply not possible. You can only give the client the option of downloading it. Whether or not they do so, and what they'd do with the file after downloading it, is out of your control.